# Como ignorar arquivos de testes com glob?

Tags: glob

Meu projeto é estruturado mais ou menos assim:

```
dist
  - *
node_modules
  - *
source
  - *.js
  - *.spec.js
  - *.test.js
  - *.vue
  - __tests__
tests
  - *.js
  - *.spec.js
  - *.test.js
```

Eu estou tentando criar um glob para pegar apenas os arquivos `vue` e `js`, mas não estou sabendo como retiro arquivos `spec.js` e `test.js` do diretório source.

Meu glob atual está assim: `project/!(node_modules|dist|__tests__|tests)**/*.+(!(spec|test)|vue|js)`

Ele pega tudo dentro da pasta `source` com exceção da pasta `__tests__`. Agora queria saber como consigo fazer com que ele pegue apenas `js` e não os `spec.js` e `test.js`.